# rails stored array of 10000 ids in session/users table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, web

I have a situation where a user has acess to multiple systems(10,000 for example). Each system is associated with a system_id.
We currently use a web service to determine what the list of systems the user has access to.

But, the issue I am facing is to retireve the list, I have to call this web service on each page of the app, which is likely to cause perfomance issue as more & more systems get added to the user.

One thought was, the first time when the user logs in, we get the list of system ids that user has access to and store in as an array of ids in a sessions or internal users table.

And  going forward use that table on subsequent pages

Would that be a bad idea or can i get any other alternatives?

Comment: Add index in your DB, if you use SGDB 10000 lines it represents nothing.

Comment: Storing data in the session purely to avoid hitting the database is a bad idea - it's not what the session is for.  But you can use **caching** for this sort of thing - look at `redis` https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails or `memcache` https://github.com/mperham/dalli